# quotient set A/R if R is an euqivalence relation on A A/R is a partition of A

Tags: elementary-set-theory, relations

I am struggeling with figuring out how to stat with this proof. I understand how to go about this if I need to prove that R is a partition of A. But the quotient set is confusing me.

Prove that: 
IF $R$ is an equivalence relation on set $A$. Then A modulo R,
$A/R = \{[x]_R|x\in A\}$, is a partition of A.

Any hints on how to get started would be appreciated!

Comment: The first hint : what does a partition mean? Even element of $A$ is in some partition, but isn't in more than one partition. You can start by showing that every element is in some partition, this should be easy from the definition of  $A/R$.

Comment: This is a great exercise in using definitions! What is a partition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check 3 things:

1. The equivalence classes are non-empty.
2. The union of the set of equivalence classes is $A$.
3. The equivalence classes are mutually disjoint.

Now, to give a hint, compare the above three conditions you have to check with the definition of an equivalence relation on $A$:

1. $(x,x) \in R$  (reflexivity)
2. $(x,y) \in R \implies (y,x) \in R$ (symmetry)
3. $(x,y) \in R , (y,z) \in R \implies (x,z) \in R$ (transitivity)

Try to find a way to connect these three things together. Drawing a figure might help.

I will give you further hints, but do not read them unless you have tried the problem on your own:
1. Reflexivity tells you that the class of $a \in A$ contains $a$ itself. Therefore, you can find out why each class has to be non-empty and they should cover the whole set.
2. Transitivity tells you that if two different classes have something in common, they should coincide!

For the reverse direction, i.e. when you have been given a partition of a set $A$, you can define an equivalence relation on $A$. Just take your equivalence classes to be the partitioned sets themselves. Work out the details.

Now you should have a good understanding of partitioning a set and defining an equivalence relation on it. The two concepts are very similar and somehow equivalent. ;-)

Comment: Thank you very much, I really appreciate this answer and like that you didn't give away the solution right away. This is very helpful guidance and incredible useful for a lonesome learner like me!

Comment: @SandraK: I'm glad that it was helpful. I'm also an undergrad student and a lonesome learner. Apparently, this is a thing in math/physics departments.Just don't mind it and try to get as much as help you can when you're stuck on a problem or a concept. Math.SE is a great resource and everyone here is on this website to help others and learn math. :)

Answer (score 0):

If $R$ is an equivalence relation on set $A$, then $A$ modulo $R$, 
$A/R=\{[x]_R:x\in A\}$, is a partition of $A$.

$\textbf{Proof}$. The family $\{[x]_R:x\in A\}$ of sets does not contain the empty set since for each equivalence class $[x]_R$, $x\in [x]_R$. So each $[x]_R\not=\varnothing$.

Secondly, we need to show that 
$$
\bigcup_{x\in A} [x]_R = A. 
$$ 
The containment $\bigcup_{x\in A} [x]_R \subseteq A$ is clear since each set $[x]_R\subseteq A$. So we will show the other containment: 
$A \subseteq \bigcup_{x\in A} [x]_R$. 
Let $x\in A$. Then $x\in [x]_R$. So $x\in \bigcup_{x\in A}[x]_R$.

Lastly, suppose $x\not\sim_R y$ (so $x\not=y$). So $x\in [x]_R$ and $y\in [y]_R$.  If $[x]_R\cap [y]_R\not=\varnothing$, then there exists an element $z\in [x]_R\cap [y]_R$. 
So $z\sim_R x$ and $z\sim_R y$. Since $\sim_R$ is an equivalence relation, $x\sim_R y$ by transitivity. This is a contradiction. So 
$$x\not\sim_R y \mbox{ implies }[x]_R\cap [y]_R = \varnothing.
$$ 
So any two distinct equivalence classes are disjoint.

Thus, $A/R$ partitions the set $A$. $\square$